# Why do the last 3 outputs of this program return 42 instead of 24?

Tags: java

The following code returns:
42
42
24
42
42
42

I am missing something, because I am thinking that it should return 24 for the last 3 outputs. What am I missing here?

```
class Mere
{
    protected int meth = 42;

    public void printMeth() {
    System.out.println(meth);
}


class Fille extends Mere
{
    public int meth = 24;
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mere mere = new Mere();
    System.out.println(mere.meth); // 42
    mere.printMeth(); // 42

    Fille fille = new Fille(); 
    System.out.println(fille.meth); //24
    fille.printMeth(); //42

    Mere mereFille = new Fille(); //42
    System.out.println(mereFille.meth); //42
    mereFille.printMeth();
}
```

Comment: fields are not accessed polymorphically

Comment: There is no overriding or polymorphism for fields; they are shadowed.